# How to make a responsive picture

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to make a responsive picture like on this template:
http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_57569/
When you zoom out of the page, the picture scales with it. (I'm talking about the one with pipes if I'm not obvious.)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should explain specifically what exactly is stopping you from at least attempting this on your own.

Comment: I'm no web(site) developer, but shouldn't you ignore zooming in general? Since it is a browser dependent feature?

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you mean how to make sure the picture scales with the viewport? i.e. when the browser window is reduced, the picture is too?

Comment: Found the solution, it was 'background-size: cover;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you provides, it seems like background image. So you can style it like below

```
background-image: url("../images/image_name.jpg");
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
img .responsive {
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `img.responsive`, without any whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

As i see on the example page you need a resizeable "div" background. 
Example code: (change image url to yours)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
   .bg{
      background-image: url("83741.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size:100%;
      width:100%;
      height:300px;
   }
</style>
</html>
```

With "width:100%" you make the div to fit always to the page's width in this case (not perfectly, you should set the margins to zero to achieve perfect fit).
With "background-size:100%" you make a "responsive" background, and the height should be fixed, as we can see in the example you gave.